# How to perform a recursive ls using maprfs Java API?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hdfs, mapr

I wrote an app that lists all the files in HDFS, then does some processing on them. This is the part of my code that lists all the files in HDFS :

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs;
hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(url), configuration);
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> it = hdfs.listFiles(new Path(url+directory), true);
```

I want to to do the same thing with MapRFS. As a first attempt I tried to use the jars of Hadoop but it didn't work. Then I tried to use the jars that come with mapr (`/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-core.jar`) but it seems that the object FileSystem  in this jar doesn't have a method called `listFiles`. Do you know if there is an equivalent method that I can use? Is there a way to do this using Hadoop jars only? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is 'almost' perfect for MapR, and your dependencies are OK.

As you probably know MapR does not use/have, for many good reasons the concept of NameNodes. This means the way you connect to a cluster is different. You do not need to path the cluster URL into the configuration or into the path.

The following code will work:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs;
hdfs = FileSystem.get(configuration); // no need to send any cluster it is retrieved from Configuration 
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> it = hdfs.listFiles(new Path(directory), true);
```

MapR knows how to connect based on the information you have in the `/opt/mapr/conf/mapr-clusters.conf`. This file indicates what the name of the cluster and the list of [CLDB](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/51/#MapROverview/c_cldb.html) nodes.

As you can see the "hadoop code" you have written is correct and working.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but by my depencies are OK, do you mean that I should use mapr's jars or Hadoop's jars ?